# Rescue or Harvest?

Tags: bioshock

Is it better to rescue the Little Sisters in Bioshock, or just harvest them? I know you get more adam for harvesting, but can you get all the tonics without Tenenbaum's *special gifts*?

This being asked after having already obtained the `Little Sister Savior` and `Dealt With Every Little Sister` achievements the first time around.

Comment: *resisted urge to rename question to "Rescue or Harvest Little Girls"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All 53 tonics for the tonic collector achievement(if that's what you're after) can be collected in a different way other than purchasing it from a gatherer's garden. here is the complete list + where you can get each one:

http://faqs.ign.com/articles/817/817677p1.html

Oh and answering the question, rescuing them has always been better for me since you get more free stuff + Tenenbaum's help. But that's just me

Answer (score 5):

The way I understand it, either you get all the tonics by saving every little sister (because Tenenbaum has some tonics you can't get anyway else) or you get more adam to spend ON tonics (by being a cruel, child-hating adam-junkie).

So, because Tenenbaum offers unique tonics, you *must* save all of the little sisters if you're interested in collecting all the tonics. (For the other achievement, I presume?)

Comment: I don't think you'll have enough adam to buy the rest of the tonics. I certainly didn't, anyway.

Comment: As corroded listed above, you don't need to buy most of them, as they can be found instead.

Comment: I think it's important to note that you STILL get SOME ADAM if you save a little sister rather than kill her, you just don't get as much.

Comment: For every Little Sister saved you get 80 instead of 160 ADAM. But for each three saved you get an extra gift of 200 ADAM plus one plasmid. So, yes, you get 40 ADAM less every three Sisters but you get a free plasmid, which usually costs 80 ADAM. All in all, I'd say you can only profit from rescuing them.